# Load Balancer Server Accessible in Browser But not via `curl localhost`

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

These are my 3 servers.

```
Load Balancer-192.168.1.72
Server-01-192.168.1.79
Server-02-192.168.1.80
```

## In Load Balancer Server, I've configured these things in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/load-balancer.conf`

```
upstream backend{
  server 192.168.1.79:80;
  server 192.168.1.80:80;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name localhost;
  
  location / {
  proxy_pass http://backend;
  }
}
```

## In server-01, I've configured this thing in `/usr/share/nginx/html/index.html`

```
cat index.html
This is server-01
```

## In server-02, I've configured this thing in `/usr/share/nginx/html/index.html`

```
cat index.html
This is server-02
```

## The problem

The configuration is successful. But when I `curl localhost:80` , I am getting empty response(which is the content at `/usr/share/nginx/html` for load-balancer.)

What's the issue here and how can I resolve it. I suspect it's something related to DNS. But I'm not aware how I fix this issue?

I added

```
192.168.1.72 localhost
```

to `/etc/hosts` of load-balancer server.

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Do you have other configs in `/etc/nginx/conf.d` or `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`?

Comment: No, I only have `load-balancer.conf` in that place.

Comment: The issue is fixed once I changed server_name to something else, But I don't know why it fixed that.